# Stripe webhooks issue in dev environment

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a simple app - backend in Spring Boot and front in React. I implemented Stripe payments. Next step - I want to add webhooks to save changes in user entity in db whenever user changes payment plan. In local everything works well. When I redirect events to localhost app receives it and saves changes in db. The problem is after deploying to dev ...

React app is running on nginx server. Here's configuration :

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name dev.app.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/fullChain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/chain.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


   root /var/www/193.666.66.666;
   index index.html;

    # Add access log
   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

   # Add error log
   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   location /api/ {
        proxy_pass  https://dev.app.com/;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
}

    location / {
 allow all;
     error_page  405     =200 $uri;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      proxy_ssl_verify on;

    }
        location /images/ {
            alias /var/www/193.666.66.666/media/;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
}
}
```

The only difference between local and dev is SSL - however I removed SSL on backend side and now it;s only handled by nginx. Also - SSL cert is 100% valid - checked. Here's my webhook endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/webhook")
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleWebhookEvent(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestBody String payload,
            @RequestHeader("Stripe-Signature") String sigHeader) {

        System.out.println("Received webhook event:");
        System.out.println("Stripe-Signature: " + sigHeader);
        System.out.println("Payload: " + payload);
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
            String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
            System.out.println("Header: " + headerName + " = " + headerValue);
        }
        // Verify the webhook event using your Stripe webhook signing secret
        String webhookSecret = "whsec_";
      try {
            Event event = Webhook.constructEvent(payload, sigHeader, webhookSecret);

            if ("checkout.session.completed".equals(event.getType())) {

            }
            if ("customer.subscription.updated".equals(event.getType())) {
                System.out.println("WEBHOOK : " + "2" + event.getType());
                try {
                    Subscription subscription = (Subscription) event.getData().getObject();
                    String productId = subscription.getItems().getData().get(0).getPrice().getProduct();
                    Customer customer = Customer.retrieve(subscription.getCustomer());
                    String customerEmail = customer.getEmail();
                    webhookService.updateUserSubscription(customerEmail, productId);
                } catch (StripeException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());

                }

            }

            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        } catch (SignatureVerificationException | IOException e) {
            // Invalid signature
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
    }
```

In dev I cannot see logs - like event is not even being received but strange thing is - in Stripe dashboard I can see code 200 like everything went well.

[image: stripe]

I already lost 4 days and going crazy. Have spoken to Stripe support team but not succedded. ANy ideas please ?

Comment: I'm more familiar with the Stripe side of this flow, so I'm not exactly sure why you aren't seeing logs when working from dev, but am hoping some clarifying questions may move us in the right direction.   

You said when testing on localhost that you saw logs and the DB was being updated as expected. When you moved to dev, was it only the logs that stopped working? Are you still seeing writes to the DB that indicate the Event is being processed?

Comment: No, I cant see logs and db is not updating:/ like event stuck.

Comment: What happens if you remove Stripe from the flow, and make a request directly to your endpoint? Do you still see 200 responses even if your request is missing required data, or do you begin to see errors/logs at that point?